# Do context switches in the kernel include code to save the context of the floating point as a general rule of thumb?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu-architecture, floating

I'm new to Kernel coding and have been going through the *LINUX DEVICE DRIVERS* book.

Here's an excerpt from the book:

*Kernel code cannot do floating point arithmetic. Enabling floating point would
require that the kernel save and restore the floating point processor’s state on each
entry to, and exit from, kernel space—at least, on some architectures. Given that
there really is no need for floating point in kernel code, the extra overhead is not
worthwhile.*

The first line kinda implies that context switching in kernel modules do not include code to store the FP context as a general rule of thumb. However, I tried running a few floating point assembly instructions in my kernel module and it seemed to work. Wouldn't this result in incorrect results for concurrently running processes that use floating point registers?

Comment: Right, it doesn't fault, it corrupts the FPU state for user-space processes, unless you tell the kernel to save/restore the state around your in-kernel use of the FPU.